# Инициализация списков: какой метод правильнее

Tags: python, массивы

Есть два способа инициализации списка (python 3.6):

Инициализация списка -- метод 1

```
x = [[1,2,3,4]] * 3
print(x)
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Инициализация списка -- метод 2

```
y = [[1,2,3,4] for _ in range(3)]
print(y)
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Какой метод следует использовать и почему?

Comment: Это разные методы. они делают не одно и то же.

Comment: А можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый метод создаёт один объект, и дублирует ссылку на него. При изменении одного из подсписков будет меняться и содержимое других

```
a = [[1,2,3,4]] * 3
a[1][1] = 5
print(a)

[[1, 5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 3, 4]]

a = [[1,2,3,4] for i in range(3)]
a[1][1] = 5
print(a)

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Создает копию - не очень удачное выражение. Как раз копия то не создается, а дублируется ссылка, поэтому такое поведение.